# Django decorator, redirect user to 404 if they access unauthorized page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have created a decorator using `users_passes_test` and it works perfectly, but my requirement is as follows,

If user is not authenticated:

**Then user needs to be redirected to login page**

Else, if user is authenticated but doesnt have access to the page:

**Then they need to be redirected to 404page**

How to modify my decorator according to the above need ?

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME


def is_student(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: (u.is_authenticated and u.role == 'student'),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

This is my decorator, please help !

Comment: `users_passes_test` redirects when a condition is false, you will have to use something else to implement your behaviour. Is this decorator meant to be used on function or class based view?

Comment: Its for Function based view !

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can just choose to stack the decorators [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) and [@user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) and then define their respective redirect URLs:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.role == 'student', login_url='/notfound/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or to reuse a common decorator:

```
from functools import partial


def is_student(function=None, redirect_field_name=None, login_url=None, notfound_url=None):
    if function is None:
        # Handle @is_student which translates to is_student(some_view) and @is_student(...) which translates to is_student(...)(some_view). The first will automatically pass the function while the second would call the response of this decorator (the partial function below) and pass the function.
        return partial(is_student, redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name, login_url=login_url, notfound_url=notfound_url)

    decorators = [
        login_required(login_url=login_url),
        user_passes_test(lambda user: user.role == 'student', login_url=notfound_url),
    ]

    decorated_func = function
    for decorator in reversed(decorators):
        decorated_func = decorator(decorated_func)

    return decorated_func


@is_student(redirect_field_name="next", login_url="/login/", notfound_url="/notfound/")
def some_view(request, ...):
    ...
```

Comment: Ya thought of this, but no point in repeating code right ? Is there any better way /

Comment: @sixovov947 I updated my answer. I tried and it worked. Could you try if it works on your side too?